# What does loop in explain analyze statement mean?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-execution-plan, explain

I am profiling my query.

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from student;
                                              QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on student  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=7 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.035 ms
 Execution time: 0.019 ms
(3 rows)
```

I am not aware about what loop=1 mean in `Seq Scan on student  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=7 loops=1)`.

I have searched postgres documentation, but didn't find any good reference about loop parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) does talk about this:

> In some query plans, it is possible for a subplan node to be executed more than once. For example, the inner index scan will be executed once per outer row in the above nested-loop plan. In such cases, the **loops** value reports the total number of executions of the node, and the actual time and rows values shown are averages per-execution. This is done to make the numbers comparable with the way that the cost estimates are shown. Multiply by the **loops** value to get the total time actually spent in the node.